# Pandas hierarchical indexes and calculations

Tags: python, pandas

Given:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"panum": ["PA1", "PA1", "PA1", "PA2", "PA2", "PA2"], 
                   "which": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
                 "score": [88, 80, 90, 92, 95, 99]})

df.set_index(['panum', 'which'], inplace=True)
df

             score
panum which       
PA1   A         88
      A         80
      A         90
PA2   B         92
      B         95
      B         99
```

Is it possible to write something that would create a new index entry in 'which' called max which would be the max but for the level, so it would create two new rows, PA1,Max and PA2,Max?

#### Update

I have corrected the indexes. The example above is not what I meant.

```
panmum  factor  score
PA1     init    90
        resub   94
        final   93
PA2     init    60
        resub   90
        final   88
```

And my question in this better scenario would be: "I want to create a new "panum" called mean, which would have three rows, (mean, init), (mean, resub), (mean, final)".

Pseudocode would be something like df['mean'] = (df['pa1'] + df['pa2']) / 2

I know this is a different question!

Answer (score 4):

You can create new `DataFrame` of `max` values, add second level `max`,  [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to original and last [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
m = df.max(level=0).assign(max='max').set_index('max', append=True)
print (m)
           score
panum max       
PA1   max     90
PA2   max     99

df = df.append(m).sort_index()
print (df)
             score
panum which       
PA1   A         88
      A         80
      A         90
      max       90
PA2   B         92
      B         95
      B         99
      max       99
```

EDIT answer: solution is changed for `mean` by second level and `swaplevel` for correct align to final `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"panum": ["PA1", "PA1", "PA1", "PA2", "PA2", "PA2"], 
                   "factor": ["init", "resub", "final"] * 2,
                   "score": [90, 94, 93, 60, 90, 88]})

df.set_index(['panum', 'factor'], inplace=True)
print (df)
              score
panum factor       
PA1   init       90
      resub      94
      final      93
PA2   init       60
      resub      90
      final      88
```

---

```
m = (df.mean(level=1)
        .assign(factor='mean')
        .set_index('factor', append=True)
        .swaplevel(0,1))
print (m)
               score
factor factor       
mean   init     75.0
       resub    92.0
       final    90.5

df = df.append(m)
print (df)
              score
panum factor       
PA1   init     90.0
      resub    94.0
      final    93.0
PA2   init     60.0
      resub    90.0
      final    88.0
mean  init     75.0
      resub    92.0
      final    90.5
```

Comment: This is the same as what I was thinking at first.

Answer (score 2):

Append a max as we go with `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat([
    d.append(d.max().rename((n, 'max')))
    for n, d in df.groupby('panum')
])

             score
panum which       
PA1   A         88
      A         80
      A         90
      max       90
PA2   B         92
      B         95
      B         99
      max       99
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution... Is this something that people use hierarchical indexes for or am I pushing beyond its intended use?

Comment: It's not pushing the boundaries too much.  The issue is that you don't have unique indices.  The intended use of an index is to be able identify unique positions.  In that vein, adding a max is perfectly fine.  But I couldn't use a more conventional approach of shifting axes around because the index wasn't unique.  And... this type of question has been asked several times before.

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared. DIdn't see the other examples of the same question. P.s. I don't see what you mean about  "unique indexes". Each pair of panum/which are unique.

Comment: The way it is, you have `('PA2', 'B')` as an index repeted 3 times.  Once for each of the values `92`, `95`, and `99`.  When I try `data.unstack()` it attempts to take the `'which'` level and place it into the `columns` object.  However, since it isn't unique, `unstack` chokes.

Comment: Duh. Of course. I am going to correct the example above.